# How can I filter stdClass object

Tags: php, arrays, json, filter

I have data below from putting JSON to Arrays

```
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [total] => 850
    [message] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 03
                    [BLOCK] => 04
                    [MATL] => ST
                    [LENGTH] => 516.492
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 03
                    [BLOCK] => 05
                    [MATL] => SCP
                    [LENGTH] => 19.177
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 03
                    [BLOCK] => 05
                    [MATL] => ST
                    [LENGTH] => 519.355
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 03
                    [BLOCK] => 06
                    [MATL] => SCP
                    [LENGTH] => 59.713
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 03
                    [BLOCK] => 06
                    [MATL] => ST
                    [LENGTH] => 476.866
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 04
                    [BLOCK] => 03
                    [MATL] => SCP
                    [LENGTH] => 64.875
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 04
                    [BLOCK] => 03
                    [MATL] => ST
                    [LENGTH] => 44.888
                ) ....
```

I want to filter data in Array as ZONE = '03'.

Can anyone give the example code to do this?

 Thankyou.

Comment: stackoverflow.com works well when you show us what you've tried (read: paste code samples).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filer PHP Array stdClass Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026626/how-to-filer-php-array-stdclass-object)

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of array_filter http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
$input = (object)array(
  'success'=>1,
  'total'=>850,
   'data'=>array(
    (object)array('ZONE'=>'01'),
    (object)array('ZONE'=>'04'),
    (object)array('ZONE'=>'04'),
    (object)array('ZONE'=>'04'),
    (object)array('ZONE'=>'03'),
    (object)array('ZONE'=>'02')
  )
);

$output = array_filter($input->data,function($object){
  return $object->ZONE == '04';
});

print_r($output);
```

array_filter works by testing each item in the array and returning TRUE or FALSE.