# How to filer PHP Array stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, json, filter

I have data below in the array that I got from JSON like this

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://giswebcenter.mwa.co.th/mwa/ashx/Proxy.ashx");
$json_output = json_decode($page);
```

and then I have data like this when I  print_r($json_output)

```
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [total] => 850
    [message] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BRANCH] => 01
                    [ZONE] => 03
                    [BLOCK] => 04
                    [MATL] => ST
                [LENGTH] => 516.492
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 03
                [BLOCK] => 05
                [MATL] => SCP
                [LENGTH] => 19.177
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 03
                [BLOCK] => 05
                [MATL] => ST
                [LENGTH] => 519.355
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 03
                [BLOCK] => 06
                [MATL] => SCP
                [LENGTH] => 59.713
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 03
                [BLOCK] => 06
                [MATL] => ST
                [LENGTH] => 476.866
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 04
                [BLOCK] => 03
                [MATL] => SCP
                [LENGTH] => 64.875
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 04
                [BLOCK] => 03
                [MATL] => ST
                [LENGTH] => 44.888
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 04
                [BLOCK] => 05
                [MATL] => SCP
                [LENGTH] => 19.979
            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 04
                [BLOCK] => 05
                [MATL] => ST
                [LENGTH] => 28.591
            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BRANCH] => 01
                [ZONE] => 04
                [BLOCK] => 07
                [MATL] => SCP
                [LENGTH] => 38.967
            )
        )
)
```

I'd like to filter data in the array as ZONE='03' 

and I've tried this code with array_filter() but noting.

```
function filterZone($obj)
{
    return $obj['data']->BRANCH == "01";
}
$BRANCH = array_filter($json_output, 'filterZone');
print_r($BRANCH);
```

Can anyone help or suggest me to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I filter stdClass object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025075/how-can-i-filter-stdclass-object)

Comment: @Sadikhasan It is a duplicate because both questions are from the same user, within 2 hours. I don't care if they got an answer previously or not, it's a waste of mine and others time, and is not fair. It's simply not cricket!

Comment: @James You are right!!! we have to `close` this question.

Comment: Sorry @James, Im a new user and  I didnt intend to post duplicate. I cant find the way to delete question on the previous.

Comment: If you didn't intend to post a duplicate, may I politely ask you what you did intend by posting a question the same as one you posted 2 hours previous?

Comment: I'd like to add more detail. I dont know to find the way to delete the previous post. If you are administrator, Can you close the previous question for me or you tell the way to do it?

Comment: The community vote to close based on duplicate (you cannot close this question now there is an answer). You shouldn't have raised a new question really, and instead edited and worked on your previous one. There is an answer in your previous question, but you used this new question to state that answer did not work for you. So you are spreading info and data over two questions and so creating potential confusion. You should also read through the help center, to learn how to use the site to your advantage. If you get too many questions closed you lose the ability to ask new questions.

Comment: Ok. I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward.  You're trying to array_filter something that isn't really an array (or at least the array you're attempting to iterate over).

You want to run something more like this:

```
function filterZone($obj)
{
    return $obj['ZONE'] == '03';
}
$BRANCH = array_filter($json_output->data, 'filterZone');
print_r($BRANCH);
```

Comment: This is a dupe question from the same user. Why answer it?

Comment: The duplication hadn't been called out when I started, it was almost effortless to answer, and it turns out that the duplicate is actually a different question if you read it beyond just the source.

Comment: Fair enough. Although, the only difference is this question has a little "addition" from the answer from the previous question, which should have been discussed etc in the previous one, not a new one raised.